# Lookup column exceeds List View Threshold

Tags: indexing, sharepoint-online

I have created a list which contains records/list items more than the list view threshold which is 5000.

I have also created a site column (as lookup) which points to a column in this parent list.

I have added this site column to a library. And I uploaded a document. But when I edit the properties of the document, I could not update value for this lookup column. The error is showing as:

> This is a lookup column that displays data from another list that currently exceeds the List View Threshold defined by the administrator (5000).”

So I have indexed this column in the parent list. from list settings -> indexed columns -> add a column

But still I'm getting this error.

The details of column in parent list is given below:

Type: Single Line of Text & Not Unique

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we can use SPAutocomplete of SPServices library/REST API to avoid List View Threshold issue. Check the articles below.

[Similar thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0e8f8aeb-1b51-4170-a917-c9bcfdb0f573/this-is-a-lookup-column-that-displays-data-from-another-list-that-currently-exceeds-the-list-view?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

[Automatic Parent/Child List Relationships for Large Lists in SharePoint](http://www.paitgroup.com/automatic-parentchild-list-relationships-for-large-lists-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Any suggestions on how to incorporate it to a modern list view?